# PHP cURL - Cookie required to register?

Tags: php, forms, cookies, curl

I am trying to use PHP cURL to submit a form on a remote server. All fields on the page are filled out as desired, but the form will not submit. The submit button looks like:

```
<input type="submit" name="process" value="Register" id="process-register" class="input-submit process-register">
```

In my `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, I am using `&process=Register`. Is it possible that this form is not submitting because a cookie is required? If so, can I create this cookie using cURL?

Edit:
The website containing the form is rotten tomatoes. Specifically http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/member/register

Comment: Yes, maybe they're using session!

Comment: Without knowing the website, there's no way for us to know if the reason for the failure is because it needs a cookie.

Comment: If you think it needs cookies, see the `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` options.

Comment: Which website? You only posted a little bit of HTML. I see no cookies here :D

Comment: Are you allowed to automate registrations on rottentomatoes?